# Devise generated mailer URLs with devise_for in Rails scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm building a Rails application with a Javascript framework, so Rails is serving the backend API.

For now, the app is simply implementing all the devise views and actions.

In order to do so, the Rails app accepts only JSON calls to its `/api/` URLs, and requires that Devise is working with JSON calls only, so that I defined them like the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :api, module: :api, constraints: { format: 'json' } do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {
      confirmations: 'devise/confirmations',
      registrations: 'devise/registrations',
      sessions: 'sessions'
    }

    resources :users
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'home#index'
  get '*path', to: 'home#index'
end
```

To explain what is going on here:

- First part is defining the API URLs including the devise ones and defines the API resources (for now only `:users`)
- Then it defines the `root` route
- Finally forwards any calls to the Javascript router (allowing to manage page reload or external links like the email links).

All is working fine with this, excepted the account confirmation email link.
The confirmation email sent has a link including `/api/` (http://localhost:3001/api/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=XLDVqqMZwXg6dszyV_nc) while it should be without (Expected URL: http://localhost:3001/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=XLDVqqMZwXg6dszyV_nc).

How can I make devise sending the confirmation email (and all the other emails) without the `/api/` part?

**Update**

Looking deeper the devise source code I found that [the confirmation mailer view template](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb#L5) is using the `confirmation_url` Rails named route, which is correct.

In my case, I need ALL the devise routes to be limited to the `/api/` route, and to the JSON format, excepted few routes to be 2 times defined: a first time out of the `/api/` scope in HTML format (which will be forwarded to my JavaScript app), and a second route within the `/api/` scope which will be called by the JavaScript app.

**Example:** Expected account creation confirmation execution stack

1. Rails receives the request to `/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=XLDVqqMZwXg6dszyV_nc`
2. Rails forward the request to the Javascript router
3. Javascript framework loads the corresponding page
4. Javascript page loads a service which will call the `/api/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=XLDVqqMZwXg6dszyV_nc` Devise route to confirm the account

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply add the two additional routes after the initial API routes. Like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :api, module: :api, constraints: { format: 'json' } do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {
      confirmations: 'devise/confirmations',
      registrations: 'devise/registrations',
      sessions: 'sessions'
    }

    resources :users
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    confirmations: 'devise/confirmations',
    registrations: 'devise/registrations'
  }

  root to: 'home#index'
  get '*path', to: 'home#index'
end
```

It is hard to say for sure without also seeing the front end code, but it is fine to have both routes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try but my first though is that this will also accepts the HTTP routes to access the HTML devise pages and confirm the account, or am I missing something?

Comment: Okay but I don't want that. I want to users to go through the Javascript application only to render the views, never through the Devise views.

Comment: If you don't want those routes, simply have them redirect to the api route on the controller level. If you are using an SPA, it should redirect to the route index and then the SPA routing tool handles showing the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can solve your problem.

1. Make the links in the emails be of `json` format (have '.json' at the end)

or

2. Allow actions for links from emails to be available through `html` (without `format: 'json'` constraint).

This example shows how to do it for email confirmation action.

```
scope :api, module: :api, constraints: { format: 'json' } do
  # skip routes generation for `confirmations` controller
  devise_for :users, skip: [:confirmations]

  # add allowed `confirmations` actions manually (all except for `show`)
  as :user do
    get 'confirmation/new', to: 'devise/confirmations#new', as: :new_user_confirmation
    post 'confirmation', to: 'devise/confirmations#create'
  end
end

# add `confirmations#show` action outside of `/api` scope to be available from email link by `html`
as :user do
  get 'confirmation', to: 'devise/confirmations#show', as: :user_confirmation
end
```

If you don't want to use Devise's HTML views and actions, you can customize Devise controllers or write your own. This example shows how to customize Devise confirmations controller:

```
# app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    # do whatever you want
  end
end 

# config/routes.rb
scope :api, module: :api, constraints: { format: 'json' } do
  # tell Devise to use your custom confirmations controller
  devise_for :users, controllers: {confirmations: "confirmations"}
end
```

**Updated**

Also, if you want your email links to have nothing to do with Devise API, you can customize the Devise mailer views to change the email texts and put there the links you need.

The `rails generate devise:views` command will generate standard Devise views including mailer templates that you can customize.

Comment: Like the other answer, this will use the Devise's HTML views and actions while I want my Javascript app to handle all the view part, and let the back (`/api/`) to handle the actions. I don't want to allow the confirmation actions, I want them to be part of my backend API and my front managing all the views.

Comment: What about the first option? (".json" links)

Comment: Well I don't understand it. Why having the JSON and HTML format would help? The Javascript app use JSON to talk with the API, the user uses HTML to access the app.

Comment: Updated the answer to explain how to not use Devise views and actions.

Comment: Sorry it looks like I'm not clear enough. All I want is that Devise is part of my API (registering users and so on), which is already working today, and I want my Javascript app to manage all the view stuff. My issue is that the URL of the link from the sent emails from Devise are including the `/api/` part, which I don't want so that the call is redirected to the Javascript app, and the JS app call through the API Devise. Is it more clear?

Comment: Updated the answer )

Comment: Thank you @chumakoff, I know this option, but it's fine to remind it :). In the other hand I'm more on a way to patch the Mailer so that the Rails named routes used by Devise are overriden and the views are untouched. My goal is to build something completely transparent for the developers who wants to build JS apps the clean way.