# Rails routes : Change path_prefix from a Mailer or Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**General question**

How can I change the `path_prefix` value from a Controller or a Mailer so that the generated URLs. when using Rails named routes, are built with the new value?

**What I tried already**

As of now, in a Mailer, I tried to override the `url_options` and the `default_url_options` methods in order to inject the `path_prefix` I need, but it didn't work.

The only thing that could work is to override each used named routes in order to amend the generated URLs ... but it's a lot of work and looks crappy to me.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

As explained with more details in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226896/devise-generated-mailer-urls-with-devise-for-in-rails-scopes), I have Devise included in my `/api` scope so that all the views are managed by my JavaScript app, and all actions (register a new user, change password etc ...) is managed from the JavaScript app, to the backend app, through the API.
But the issue that Device emails are sending URLs including the `/api` `path_prefix` which make then not working (and not correct).

Comment: can you try 
   lookup_context.prefixes.prepend 'prefix_keyword_here'  in controller

Comment: Thank you @AnandJose for your comment, but LookupContect seems to be related to template paths https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/LookupContext, isn't it?

Comment: You are digging in the wrong place. Just take the needed Devise actions out of the `/api` scope.

Comment: Okay @chumakoff, I tried that for days before to come to this point. Do you have an example that you could post as an answer please? It would close my 2 questions !

Comment: Show how you add Devise routes in your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: And explain why URLs including the `/api` prefix don't work for user confirmation by the link from email in your case

Comment: You'll find everything here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226896/devise-generated-mailer-urls-with-devise-for-in-rails-scopes

Comment: Added an answer there

Comment: Thank you @chumakoff but it's not what I'm looking for. If I'm not clear enough, feel free to ask me more.